# Замена файла .dll в каталоге проекта C#

Tags: c#, dll

Допустим есть проект и была создана библиотека, которую использует данная программа. Что будет, если после компиляции заменить файл библиотеки на новый? Ведь вполне может возникнуть ситуация, когда одну dll заменили другой. Будет ли "подхвачена" библиотека или есть какая-то зависимость, например, от версии старой сборки dll?

Comment: Под DLL Вы имеете в виду сборку .NET? Если да, в проекте есть ссылка на эту DLL или Вы хотите загружать ее динамически?

Comment: @SerafimProzorov, есть проект. В нем \bin\Debug\. По этому  пути находится somelibrary.dll. В проекте біла ссылка на эту somelibrary.dll. И допустим файл somelibrary.dll заменить на одноименный somelibrary.dll но другого содержания.

Comment: @AVD - вы попробуйте, это несложно воспроизвести. Такие штуки полезнее самому пробовать :)

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то в проекте есть ссылка на эту библиотеку, то есть происходит ранее связывание. Естественно, что при сборке она попадает в каталог /bin/Debug. В этом случае нельзя подложить даже другую версию той же библиотеки, вернее, можно, но тогда надо будет в app.config прописать редиректы (почитать можно здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions). Подложить некую совсем левую либу, естественно, нельзя.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov, спасибо